# Packet error with express JS [Serverless lambda/Netlify Functions]

Tags: node.js, express, lambda, serverless, netlify-function

I'm migrating my express JS app to Netlify functions. When both running the project locally and in production, I receive this error in the console upon request, and the process is terminated.

Has anyone run into this issue before and would know how to fix it?

```
Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence.
at p._parsePacket (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:320:64791)
at p._parsePacket (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:320:73520)
at p.write (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:320:67748)
at p.write (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:320:61259)
at Socket.<anonymous> (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:71:2421)
at Socket.<anonymous> (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:71:1523)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
--------------------
at p._enqueue (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:320:62637)
at p.handshake (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:320:61382)
at _.connect (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:71:3293)
at Object.<anonymous> (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:154:2993)
at n (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:1:158)
at Object.<anonymous> (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:154:58603)
at n (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:1:158)
at Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:1:957
at Object.<anonymous> (Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\functions\app.js:1:967)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Q:\React Apps\Pulse API\pulse-api\node_modules\netlify-lambda\lib\serve.js:122:17 {code: 'PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE', fatal: true}
```

Simplified error:

PROTOCOL_INCORRECT_PACKET_SEQUENCE

Comment: Check webpack.js, there is some version mismatch
Or put this 
optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }

Comment: @rajanbhadauria Do you know where webpack.js would be in node_moduels?

Comment: It is version miss-match issue, any node package version is have conflict

Comment: Currently only using these dependencies. How would I go about fixing a version miss-match? Is it an issue with npm/node or an individual dependency?

"dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "chalk": "^4.1.1",
  "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "mysql": "^2.18.1",
  "netlify-lambda": "^2.0.11",
  "serverless-http": "^2.7.0"
 }